# millimeters to feet/inches

Tags: php, math, units-of-measurement

I was wondering if anyone could help me create a function that will turn millimeters into feet/inches.

Example: 5280mm will be returned as 17ft / 3.87inches (or 17'3")

I know that there's 304.8mm in a foot, which gives me 17.322834645669 (using the same example above) but I'm not sure how to then format it into something more legible.

```
function getMeasurements($mm) { 
    return ($mm/304.8); 
}
```

Comment: HINT: You can use the modulo operator and the integer division operator to get the inches and the feet, e.g. to translate 14 inches into 1'2".

Comment: So your question is _really_ about formatting numbers for output; nothing to do with maths or conversions or units whatsoever.

Comment: I'll have a look into that, thanks.

Comment: @Tomalak. Obviously there is a mathematical process in turning one unit of measurement into another unit of measurement, so yes, my question does have to do with mathematics, units and conversions, but thanks for your completely useless comment.

Comment: @Soulie: Nonsense. You've already _done_ the conversion. Your question appears to be about _formatting the result_.

Comment: Last time I checked units of measurements require mathematical equations to convert from one thing to another. But somehow you must know better about what I actually require huh.

Comment: But thank you to Eric who actually helped me out, rather than whatever kind of moderator you are just being a troll rather than being useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And if anyone is looking to do the same thing, this is what I used to calculate mm to ft/inches:

```
function getMeasurements($mm) {

    $inches = ceil($mm/25.4);
    $feet = floor(($inches/12));
    $measurement = $feet."'".($inches%12).'"';

    return $measurement;
}
```

Which returns something like: 17'3".

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is format the number, use [`number_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)