# PHP centimeters to feet

Tags: php

I'm busy figuring out how to convert centimeters to feet with a php script.
I couldn't find anything on the internet so I hope you guys can help.
I get the centimeters out of my database like this '182'
How can I automatically convert it into 5' 11" ?

Thanks,
Julan ter Weele

Comment: You write a formula.  For the record, 1cm is 0.0328084 feet..

Answer (score 1):

You write a formula. For the record, 1cm is 0.0328084 feet

182 * 0.0328084 = 5.9 feet
.9 feet is 10.8

Put the two together and your answer is 5 feet 10.8 inches.

Comment: In case you're interested.  I wrote an Android app to do these sorts of conversions.  I created a bunch of conversion tables to handle any sorts of inputs.  The method is essentially the same thing as this.  If you want to see how it works:  http://dpoisn.com/demos/AndroidDev/metricconverter/default.php

Answer (score -3):

From the following [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906801/millimeters-to-feet-inches) (not tested by myself):

```
function getMeasurements($mm) {

    $inches = ceil($mm/25.4);
    $feet = floor(($inches/12));
    $measurement = $feet."'".($inches%12).'"';

    return $measurement;
}
```

Needs to convert to centimeters...

Comment: Not only is this not your answer (meaning you should have flagged this thread as a duplicate to reference this SO link), you also didn't test it and it doesn't do what the OP requested...